# C - How to increment a pointer to a string through a function?

Tags: c, pointers

I want to execute the following code, but through a function.

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main(){
    char* string = "hello_World";
    string++;
    printf("%s\n", string);
    // ignore memory leak for sake of quiz
    return 0;
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ello_World
```

Now instead of incrementing the pointer inside `main` I tried to pass the reference of the pointer to a function and then increment it.

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    void myfunc(char** param){
    param++;
    }

    int main(){
    char* string = "hello_World";
    myfunc(&string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return 0;
    }
```

But the OUTPUT was `hello_World`

Can you please tell me what is happening in the code that I wrote and how can I change it for the desired result?

Comment: you incrementing pointer to pointer.... use  (*param)++; inside your function

Answer (score 3):

You incremented the pointer to the pointer, you would need `(*param)++;`

Answer (score 3):

The memory could be looking like the following. The `0x1122*****` represent some address of the byte below it. Each `+---+` box represents one byte with the value inside. Below are the function names with variable names. The `---->` arrows represent "points to" relation between pointer and memory. The illustration assumes a pointer has 4 bytes and data are stored in big endian, which is most probably not true on the architecture you are running, but it's just to illustrate the point.

```
0x11223000                                       0x11223300                              0x11223344
+------+------+------+------+                    +------+------+------+------+           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+
| 0x11 | 0x22 | 0x33 | 0x00 | . . . . . . . . .  | 0x11 | 0x22 | 0x33 | 0x44 | . . . . . | h | e | l | l | e | _ | W | o | r | l | d | 0x00 |
+------+------+------+------+         +--------->+------+------+------+------+           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+
                                      |                                                  ^
+---------------------------+---------+          +---------------------------+-----------+
       myfunc::param                                     main::string
```

When you do `param++` in `myfunc` you are incrementing the *value* of `param`, not the value it points to. Pointers are increment by the size they are pointing to, so `param` beeing `char**` will be incremented by `sizeof(char*)`. In my illustration above, a pointer has 4 bytes, so doing `param++` increments `param = 0x11223300` to `param = 0x11223304` and it points somewhere after `main::string` into some unknown memory region.

If you mean to do this:

```
0x11223300                              0x11223344
+------+------+------+------+           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+
| 0x11 | 0x22 | 0x33 | 0x45 | . . . . . | h | e | l | l | e | _ | W | o | r | l | d | 0x00 |
+------+------+------+------+           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+
                                            ^
+---------------------------+---------------+
        main::string
```

Then you have to increment the `string` pointer inside `main`. Because `param` points to `string`, you may `(*param)++` - increment the value of what the `param` points to, so increment the `string` pointer inside `main`. Because `string` is a `char*`, it will be incremented by `sizeof(char)` - which is `1`.

Answer (score 3):

In `myfunc()` function, the pointer `param` is pointing to `string` pointer. It will look something like this:

```
        ---
  param |-|--
        --- |
            |
            |
           ---
   string  |-|----
           ---   |
                 |
                 |
                 --------------------------
                 |h|e|l|l|o|_|W|o|r|l|d|\0|
                 --------------------------
```

When you do `param++`, it will result in incrementing the pointer by the size of pointer<sup>1)</sup> on your platform because `param` can point to a `char` pointer. Assume that size of pointer is `8` (`64` bit platform) and assume the address of `string` pointer is `100`, then `param++` will result in pointer `param` pointing to `108` address. Note that it will not affect  `string` pointer in anyway. It will look something like this:

```
                             108
                   ---       ---
param++ -->  param |-|-------| |
                   ---       ---
            
           
           ---
   string  |-|----
           ---   |
                 |
                 |
                 --------------------------
                 |h|e|l|l|o|_|W|o|r|l|d|\0|
                 --------------------------
```

Now, when you print the `string` in `main()` function, you are getting the output "hello_World".

To demonstrate this, I have added few `printf()` statement in your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(char** param){
    printf ("param : %p\n", (void *)param);
    printf ("*param : %p\n", (void *)*param);
    param++;
    printf ("param : %p\n", (void *)param);
    printf ("*param : %p\n", (void *)*param);
}

int main(void){
    char* string = "hello_World";
    printf ("string : %p\n", (void *)string);
    myfunc(&string);
    printf ("string : %p\n", (void *)string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
string : 0x10a654f97
param : 0x7ffee55abad0
*param : 0x10a654f97
param : 0x7ffee55abad8  ======> result of incrementing param
*param : 0xcb7d025      ======> result of incrementing param
string : 0x10a654f97    ======> not affected
hello_World
```

To get the desired behaviour, in the `myfunc()` function, you should first dereference the `param` pointer to get the `string` pointer and then increment it i.e. you should do `(*param)++`. It will result in increment the `string` pointer by size of a `char`<sup>1)</sup>:

```
                       ---
                 param |-|--
                       --- |
                           |
                           |
                          ---
(*param)++  -->   string  |-|-------
                          ---      |
                                   |
                                   |
                                --------------------------
                                |h|e|l|l|o|_|W|o|r|l|d|\0|
                                --------------------------
```

Demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(char** param){
    printf ("param : %p\n", (void *)param);
    printf ("*param : %p\n", (void *)*param);
    (*param)++;
    printf ("param : %p\n", (void *)param);
    printf ("*param : %p\n", (void *)*param);
}

int main(){
    char* string = "hello_World";
    printf ("string : %p\n", (void *)string);
    myfunc(&string);
    printf ("string : %p\n", (void *)string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
string : 0x100de5f97
param : 0x7ffeeee1aad0
*param : 0x100de5f97
param : 0x7ffeeee1aad0
*param : 0x100de5f98
string : 0x100de5f98
ello_World
```

---

1. When increment a pointer, it gets incremented in steps of the object size that the pointer can point to.